# Why does `cat` followed by appending to a file seem to overwrite itself?

Tags: linux, cat

Consider the following two (sets of) commands:

```
$ cat *.d | wc -l
```

and

```
$ rm -f tmp
$ cat *.d >> tmp
$ cat tmp | wc -l
```

I would expect the two of these to output the same value. However, when I run this on a particular directory that I have, I see the following:

```
$ cat *.d | wc -l
7026
```

and in comparison:

```
$ rm -f tmp
$ cat *.d >> tmp
$ cat tmp | wc -l
295
```

It seems like my `cat` is tripping over its own tail, if you can excuse the pun. What is happening here? Note that if I use `>` instead of `>>` then I get the expected output of `7026`.

**Edit:**

For a bit more information, the issue is arising on a local CentOS 7 VM (which is running on a Mac). I should not that I have just run the "same thing" on a separate VM and I do not get the same output as above, both sets of commands return the same output.

In both cases, the version of `cat` is 8.22, and the version of `bash` is 4.2.46(2).

Comment: What are the files you are `cat`-ing?  What does `ls -l -d *.d` output?

Comment: They're a collection of dependency files generated by a build process. They are just plain text "makefiles".

Comment: I mean, it is giving me consistently the same output, so "it works on my computer" :D

Comment: If I compare `tmp` to some of the files, I can see that the initial segment of the file matches the very last file ordered alphabetically. So that seems interesting.

Comment: I don't think we will be able to help unless you can get us a reproducible example. Without access to your machine, we will have to just assume that something else is writing to `tmp` since there's no other answer.

Comment: Here's a non-reproducible example (or, maybe a hint for what the issue is): the CentOS VM has a shared folder with the host OS. In such a shared directory (I have tried now several), I see the issue above. However, in a non-shared directory it behaves as expected.

Comment: It's a vagrant Virtualbox VM using the default `config.vm.synced_folder` settings.

Comment: A resurgence of [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/1612) decade-old VirtualBox bug?

Comment: Various thoughts :: Use `tee` to execute `cat` only once but send the output to `wc` as well as to a file. This will ensure that both are counting the same output ; Start with `cat *.d | tee tmp | wc -l` then use `wc -l tmp` ; Experiment with tee options --append & --output-error [[ https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html ]] Your Description & Comments sound like Gilles is right .... You could skip the `cat *.d` and use `seq 1 100000` to eliminate those files ....

Comment: Silly question No. 1... This `cat`, this is `/usr/bin/cat` and not a script/procedure/alias etc?

Comment: @Prem - Using `tee` as you suggested causes the two of them to match in output. And you are also correct, `seq 1 100000` is just as good an example of the issue.

Comment: Oh, OK; I think you should Experiment with tee options --append & --output-error to verify that the Issue occurs and what errors are thrown ....

Comment: My version of `tee`  (GNU coreutils 8.22) does not include `--output-error`; however, `-a` reproduces the error.

Comment: It definitely looks like the error linked above, but it isn't exactly the same as it. And it appears that `seq 1 1859` works fine, while `seq 1 1860` is the first one that fails.

Comment: Oh, `seq 1 1859` contains 8188 bytes which is short of 8192 bytes, while `seq 1 1860` contains 8193 bytes which exceeds 8192 bytes ; Implying that (1) block size is 8K bytes (2) every write is a block (3) every new block is overwriting the existing block (4) this is leaving only the last block.

Comment: That is extremely interesting. Looking at the output `seq 1 10000 >> tmp`, then the resulting filesize is exactly 8192 bytes. Somewhat similarly, the output of my `cat *.d >> tmp` operations, the size of `tmp` matches the size of the largest file.

Comment: So this raises the natural question: What exactly is this a bug _in_? I assume it's a virtualbox issue?

Comment: Try starting new VM with some other OS (Debian) to check that shared folder has the Issue : Either it will eliminate GuestOS (CentOS 7) or it will confirm that GuestOS is culprit. If it is not GuestOS, that leaves HostOS & VirtualBox ; Then try alternative Virtualization Tools (Eg VMWare) with similar scenario to check whether it is Mac Issue (occurring on all GuestOS + Virtualization tool Combos) or occurring only in CentOS or only in VirtualBox ; VirtualBox already had similar (but resolved) Bug in the Past ( Gilles has listed that ) hence I guess a new code Path has similar Issues ....